# Problema con sección con background y texto dinámico jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Mi situación es la siguiente:
La sección web que estoy trabajando se compone de la descripción de un categoría madre y al pié de la sección tiene un menú para navegar entre los subcategorías. El fin es que los usuario cuando ingresan vean la descripción del servicio madre y puedan navegar entre las subcategorías y todo sucede en la misma sección sin recargar y reemplazando los textos y el background cada vez que hacen `click`. Por ahora lo que logré armar es esto:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.btn-div1').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
        $("#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4").hide();
        $("#div0").fadeToggle("slow");
        $("section").css("background", "red");
  } else {
        $("#div0, #div2, #div3, #div4").hide();
        $("#div1").fadeToggle("slow");
        $("section").css("background", "yellow");
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});

$('.btn-div2').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
        $("#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4").hide();
        $("#div0").fadeToggle("slow");
        $("section").css("background", "red");
  } else {
        $("#div0, #div1, #div3, #div4").hide();
        $("#div2").fadeToggle("slow");
        $("section").css("background", "blue");
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});

$('.btn-div3').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
        $("#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4").hide();
        $("#div0").fadeToggle("slow");
        $("section").css("background", "red");
  } else {
        $("#div0, #div1, #div2, #div4").hide();
        $("#div3").fadeToggle("slow");
        $("section").css("background", "green");
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
});

</script>
<style type="text/css">
section{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: red;
    transition: background 1s linear;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div id="div0" style="width:200px;padding:50px">CATEGORIA MADRE</div>
        <div id="div1" style="width:200px;padding:50px;display:none;">SUB CATEGORIA 1</div>
        <div id="div2" style="width:200px;padding:50px;display:none;">SUB CATEGORIA 2</div>
        <div id="div3" style="width:200px;padding:50px;display:none;">SUB CATEGORIA 3</div>
        <button class="btn-div1">Click to fade SUB CATEGORIA 1</button><br><br>
        <button class="btn-div2">Click to fade SUB CATEGORIA 2</button><br><br>
        <button class="btn-div3">Click to fade SUB CATEGORIA 3</button><br><br>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Ahora el problema surge cuando el usuario hace 2 `clicks` en la subcategoria, este debe devolver el resultado de la categoría madre. Básicamente como un **ON / OFF** de subcategorias. El problema como lo tengo armado es que hacen `click` en SUB CATEGORIA 1 y después en SUB CATEGORIA 2 y si vuelven a hacer `click` en SUB CATEGORIA 1 muestra la CATEGORIA madre. Son muy novato en `jquery` y me estoy metiendo con este proyecto, el problema es que tengo tiempos muy cortos para poder seguir investigando y ya estoy trabado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema radica en que para hacer el efecto de `show / hide` de los elementos , valida el estado en su `data-clicks` del botón *(true o false)* .

La solución más sencilla sería  setear a `false` estos valores de los botones a los cuales no pertenece el evento click. es decir si se produce el evento en el botón 1  , para botón 2  y botón 3 deberá setear el valor  de clicks a false `$('.btn-div2').data("clicks", false);`  de los dos botones restantes

```js
$('.btn-div1').click(function() {
   $('.btn-div2').data("clicks", false);
   $('.btn-div3').data("clicks", false);
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
        $("#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4").hide();
        $("#div0").fadeToggle("slow");
        $("section").css("background", "red");
  } else {
        $("#div0, #div2, #div3, #div4").hide();
        $("#div1").fadeToggle("slow");
        $("section").css("background", "yellow");
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});

$('.btn-div2').click(function() {
    $('.btn-div1').data("clicks", false);
   $('.btn-div3').data("clicks", false);
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
        $("#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4").hide();
        $("#div0").fadeToggle("slow");
        $("section").css("background", "red");
  } else {
        $("#div0, #div1, #div3, #div4").hide();
        $("#div2").fadeToggle("slow");
        $("section").css("background", "blue");
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});

$('.btn-div3').click(function() {
   $('.btn-div1').data("clicks", false);
   $('.btn-div2').data("clicks", false);
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
        $("#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4").hide();
        $("#div0").fadeToggle("slow");
        $("section").css("background", "red");
  } else {
        $("#div0, #div1, #div2, #div4").hide();
        $("#div3").fadeToggle("slow");
        $("section").css("background", "green");
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
        <div id="div0" style="width:200px;padding:50px">CATEGORIA MADRE</div>
        <div id="div1" style="width:200px;padding:50px;display:none;">SUB CATEGORIA 1</div>
        <div id="div2" style="width:200px;padding:50px;display:none;">SUB CATEGORIA 2</div>
        <div id="div3" style="width:200px;padding:50px;display:none;">SUB CATEGORIA 3</div>
        <button class="btn-div1 btn">Click to fade SUB CATEGORIA 1</button><br><br>
        <button class="btn-div2 btn">Click to fade SUB CATEGORIA 2</button><br><br>
        <button class="btn-div3 btn">Click to fade SUB CATEGORIA 3</button><br><br>
    </section>
```